# Selenium and Geckodriver issue with creating a webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I have a piece of code in a python crawler that used to work.  I installed it on a new system, and am trying to get the right dependencies now.  When using geckodriver 0.13.0 and executing the following code:

```
        def login(self):
            print self.colors.OKBLUE + "Logging into my site as User: " + self.config.email + self.colors.ENDC
            username = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.my_user_field')
            for c in self.config.email:
                    print "Sending key: " + c
                    username.send_keys(c + "")
```

I get the following error:

```
Sending key: b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    crawler.start()
  File "/home/tyrick/dev/pycrawlers/sc/src/main/python/new.py", line 39, in start
    self.login()
  File "/home/tyrick/dev/pycrawlers/sc/src/main/python/new.py", line 147, in login
username.send_keys(c)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
```

I read in a few places that geckodriver has a bug with this, and I should use 0.16.0.  So I've tried that as well as 0.17.0, but am now getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    crawler = New()
  File "/home/tyrick/dev/pycrawlers/sc/src/main/python/new.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: elementScrollBehavior was not a the name of a known capability or a valid extension capability
```

It's as if I now can't even initialize the driver.  I am using Selenium 3.4.3, which from what I read is fine.

If anyone can guide me towards a solution, I’d appreciate it much! Thanks

Comment: Hey Tyrick! Still care to debug this problem? Have you taken a look at my suggestion and request? Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You are right, you have two different issues.

> Issue with `geckodriver 0.13.0`:

This is most likely because your `c` is `undefined`.

You have to verify/assert that `self.config.email` actually returns a valid string (email). So do a check that `c` contains your expected email before issuing the `.send_keys()` command.

Another enhancement worth noting here is your lack of safety when it comes to finding the username field. You should use an **explicit wait** !

```
# Library imports
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# (...)

def login(self):
    print self.colors.OKBLUE + "Logging into my site as User: " + 
    self.config.email + self.colors.ENDC

    # Polls the DOM for 3 seconds trying to find '.my_user_field'
    username = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.my_user_field')))

    for c in self.config.email:

        # Validate 'c' is of type string
        if (str(type(c)).find('str') != -1):  
            print "Sending key: " + c
            username.send_keys(c + "")
        else:
            print "'c' is not what it used to be!"
```

Lastly, add the full snippet because it looks like you're cycling through a list of emails and sending them in the previously found username field.

> Issue with `geckodriver 0.16.0`:

This is failing because you have an issue with your driver instantiation: `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`.

Please update the question with the complete snippet of your driver declaration (including capabilities & profiles, if any). Else, it's really hard to figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: So it turns out that "c" does contain the correct email string.  You can even see in the print out above: "Sending key: b", where 'b' is the first character of my email.  I think I will try the Chrome driver and get back to you.

Comment: This issue is due to a bug with the recent firefox version (53 and above), check my response, this issue has already been fixed, and will not appear in the next release of checkodriver.

Answer (score 1):

This actually has nothing to do with your code, this is a bug with the latest release of Firefox check this [issue thread](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659) on the Geckodriver repository, you will have to :

- Downgrade to [Firefox 52.0](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox)  .
- Wait for the next release of Geckodriver.
- Download and compile  Geckodriver manually.
- Use another driver like [Chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

The best option i believe is the first one, you will also have to disable automatic updates once you downgrade to prevent Firefox from going back to the latest version (Settings->Advanced->Update->Never check for updates)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

- As per the Question heading I understand the issue is Starting Mozilla Firefox through GeckoDriver.
- As you have mentioned your `Selenium` version as 3.4.3, you can consider using any of the following either geckodriver v0.16.0 or v0.16.1 or v0.17.0
- As per your latest error stack trace the main issue is configuring the WebDriver instance.
- It is to be noted that the current Selenium-Python binding is unstable with geckodriver and looks to be Architecture specific. You can find the github [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) and [merge](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/685) here. So you may additionally need to pass the absolute path of the firefox binary as `firefox_binary` argument while initializing the **webdriver**
- Here is the working set of code block using `Selenium` version 3.4.3, geckodriver v0.17.0 & Mozilla Firefox 53.0 through Python 3.6.1 which opens the URL `http://www.python.org`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

  if __name__ == '__main__':

      binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
      driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
      driver.get("http://www.python.org")
  ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Not to be nitpicking here, but did you read/follow his error tracebacks from start to finish? :) His first issue (`0.16.0`) is **100%** a `.send_keys()` problem, and the second (`0.17.0`) has a different error than the one you pointed to (meaning **[this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884)**): A.F.A.I.K., `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` is  different from `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: elementScrollBehavior was not a the name of a known capability or a valid extension capability`

Comment: Specifying the absolute path did not help.  There was still an error with: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: elementScrollBehavior was not a the name of a known capability or a valid extension capability"

Comment: @Tyrick My Answer have nothing to do with `elementScrollBehavior`. My Answer targets your question header of Selenium/geckodriver issue. Thanks

Comment: Which exception are you referring to?  The first exception was a WebDriverException around the send_keys(). The second exception was with the elementScrollBehavior.  I didn't have any issues outside of that to my knowledge.

Comment: @Tyrick I thought you need help around your comment `It's as if I now can't even initialize the driver.` Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code, check my response

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but in reference to @iamdanchiv's answer, what does "lack of safety when it comes to finding the username field. You should use an explicit wait!" Do you mean that there is no safety in terms of bringing up an error?

Comment: And by explicit wait you mean something like time.sleep()?

Comment: No, `time.sleep()` and related commands should never be used outside the scope of debugging. An explicit wait will poll the DOM (usually every 250, or 500 ms, depends on framework) for the given amount of time. It will return the `WebElement`, or a `NoSuchElement` exception. Check **[StackOverflow SeleniumWebdriver Documentation - Waits](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/4435/wait#t=201706191154328390365)**, or the **[official documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)**, where they break-down waiting for `WebElements`. Hope it helps!