# Send Keys Error with Selenium and Geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Selenium and geckodriver, but I'm facing this error when sending keys.

```
Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", 
line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Expected 
[object Undefined] undefined to be a string
```

And the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

I'm using the most up to day version of geckodriver and Firefox. I tried downgrading but the error still remains. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium and Geckodriver issue with creating a webdriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468954/selenium-and-geckodriver-issue-with-creating-a-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in java with selenium : Expected \[object Undefined\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472172/error-in-java-with-selenium-expected-object-undefined)